# How do I escape quotes for JSON conversion in Bash

Tags: bash, printf, json

I have a file which I need to convert to a JSON string and it needs to be done via `bash`.

My test file looks like

```
1
2
'
3
4
```

Here is what's happening

```
$ LOG=$(cat file)
$ printf '{"log": "%q"}\n' "$LOG"
{"log": "$'1\n2\n\'\n3\n4'"}
```

Things seem ok like it's handling the newlines and the `'`, but it's adding a `$'` at the start and a `'` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to use three consecutive `printf`, the main one with `%s` instead of `%q`:

```
$ printf '{"log": "'; printf '%s\\n' $(<file); printf '"}\n'
{"log": "1\n2\n'\n3\n4\n"}
```

Comment: Note that this works fro the given data, but if one line said e.g. `*`, then this would be replaced by the result of `*` being used as a filename globbing pattern. It would additionally replace any whitespace with newlines.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote does not need special handling to be included in a JSON value.  Double quotes, newlines, tabs, etc. will need to be escaped or encoded though.  It is easiest to use a JSON-aware tool for doing this.  I'm mentioning [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) below.

---

```bsh
jo log=@file
```

This uses `jo` to create a JSON document with a single key, `log`, whose value will be a JSON-encoded string consisting of the contents of the file `file`.

Output given the data in the question:

```json
{"log":"1\n2\n'\n3\n4"}
```

You could also get the data base64-encoded by using

```bsh
jo log=%file
```

(I'm only mentioning this because it's a neat feature of `jo`).

Output:

```json
{"log":"MQoyCicKMwo0Cg=="}
```

---

Using `jq`:

```bsh
jq -c -Rs '{ log: . }' file
```

This reads the raw input from `file` and converts it into a single string.  This string is used as the value for a `log` key in an object which gets outputted.

The output, given the data in the question:

```json
{"log":"1\n2\n'\n3\n4\n"}
```

(Notice that the final newline is preserved here, but not in the `jo` output).

To get base64-encoded data (would you want to):

```bsh
jq -c -Rs '{ log: (.|@base64) }' file
```